# Running mysql stored procedure throws a hibernate exception: "Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'N/A' "

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

For some odd reason when I execute a mysql stored procedure via hibernate it interprets a string "N/A" as a double value and throws an error. When running the same query in mysql directly everything works fine, but Hibernate seems to think I'm trying to divide? If all things left the same "NA" the stored procedure runs with no problem via hibernate.

Any idea how to get the sting to be accepted in hibernate?

The call:

```
 def query = session.createSQLQuery("call myproc (:id, :date)")
                .setParameter("id", 168)
                .setParameter("date", "2015-02-01").executeUpdate()
```

The part of the stored procedure:

```
insert table1
      ( myvarchar255field)
        ( select "N/A"
          from table2
          where [something else happens]);
```

> org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTy>peDelegate.java:69)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:211)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:389)
>     at
>    Caused by:
>   ***com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated
>   incorrect DOUBLE value: 'N/A'     at***
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3885)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     ... 4 more

Comment: the exception references an insert in the store proc that is inserting a value of "N/A" which when changed to "NA" works with out a problem. There's something with the "/" in hibernate that's interpreting it wrong even with the quotes around it.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you use the debugger, it is definitely throwing the exception in the executeUpdate method?  Can you show your proc?

Comment: yes definitely there. I can't post the whole thing but the part that has the "N/A" string is something like this:

Comment: Your code didn't show up.  Edit your question and add it instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: sorry about that. please see above

Comment: Have you tried with single quotes instead of double quotes around N/A? I'm wondering if you have ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode enabled.  If that doesn't work, I'd be curious if `select concat('N/A')` would work.